# Grid Mode with Dynamically generated Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Does anyone know of a way to enable grid mode using rows and slidesPerRow when dynamically generating a carousel with the slickAdd event? Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? As you're new I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask